# Check if parent directory exists or not in java

Tags: java, linux

How do I check whether a parent directory is created or not before creating file in that directory? I can use file.exists() but it only checks if my file obj  is created and not my parent directory/parent path.

Comment: `File#getParentFile` combined with `File#exists` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that :

```
 file.getParentFile().exists();
```

Will return true if the parent exists, false if not.

Comment: Possible NPE if `getParentFile()` returns `null` which is possible,

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean exists();
```

that will  Tests whether the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname exists. 
.

```
String path = "URL";
File f = new File(path);
f.exists();
f.getParentFile().mkdirs(); //File with Create Dir
f.createNewFile();
```